# Why does NumPy give a different result when summing over a zero padded array?

Tags: python, numpy, wolfram-mathematica

I calculated the sum over an array and over a zero padded version of the same array:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(3635250408)

n0, n1 = int(2**16.9), 2**17

xx = np.random.randn(n0)
yy = np.zeros(n1)
yy[:n0] = xx

sx, sy = np.sum(xx), np.sum(yy)

print(f"sx = {sx}, sy = {sy}") # -> sx = -508.33773983674155, sy = -508.3377398367416
print(f"sy - sx:", sy - sx)  # -> sy - sx: -5.68434188608e-14
print("np.ptp(yy[:n0] - xx) =", np.ptp(yy[:n0] - xx)) # -> 0
```

Why don't I get identical results?

Interestingly, I am able to show similar effects in Mathematica. I am using Python 3.6 (Anaconda 5.0 with MKL support) and Numpy 1.13.3. Perhaps, could it be an MKL issue?

**Update:** @rich-l and  @jkim noted that rounding problems might be the cause. I am not convinced, because adding zero should not alter a floating point number (The problem arose, when investigating a data set of that size - where the deviations were significantly larger).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: The same issue can be seen using small `n` values: `n0, n1 = 22, 24`. (And there are probably even smaller examples.)

Comment: @unutbu very interesting - I'm able to reporduce that as well.

Comment: Same case with Python 2. Also, `np.sum(yy[:n0+1])` is equal to `sx`, but `np.sum(yy[:n0+2])` is equal to `sy` while `np.sum(yy[:n0+1]) + yy[n0+1]` is equal to `sx`. So I can't say exactly what's going on, but numpy is probably trying to do some optimizations under the hood that cause it run into a floating point error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating-point arithmetic is [not associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems):

```
In [129]: ((0.1+0.2)+0.3) == (0.1+(0.2+0.3))
Out[129]: False
```

So the order in which the items are added affects the result. 
`numpy.sum` usually uses [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation). It reverts to naive summation (from left to right) when the length of the array is [less than 8](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3685/files#diff-eb6ddd50e74f51bd4bceae1d17bfe4dcR1377) or [when summing over a strided axis](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8786#issuecomment-286864207).

Since pairwise summation recursively breaks the sequence into two groups, the
addition of zero padding affects the midpoint where the sequence gets divided and hence
alters the order in which the values are added.  And since floating-point
arithmetic is not associative, zero padding can affect the result.

For example, consider

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(3635250408)
n0, n1 = 6, 8
xx = np.random.randn(n0)
# array([ 1.8545852 , -0.30387171, -0.57164897, -0.40679684, -0.8569989 ,
#         0.32546545])

yy = np.zeros(n1)
yy[:n0] = xx
# array([ 1.8545852 , -0.30387171, -0.57164897, -0.40679684, -0.8569989 ,
#         0.32546545,  0.        ,  0.        ])
```

`xx.sum()` and `yy.sum()` are not the same value:

```
In [138]: xx.sum()
Out[138]: 0.040734223419930771

In [139]: yy.sum()
Out[139]: 0.040734223419930826

In [148]: xx.sum() == yy.sum()
Out[148]: False
```

Since `len(xx) < 8`, the values in `xx` are summed from left to right:

```
In [151]: xx.sum() == (((((xx[0]+xx[1])+xx[2])+xx[3])+xx[4])+xx[5])
Out[151]: True
```

Since `len(yy) >= 8`, [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation) is used to compute `yy.sum()`:

```
In [147]: yy.sum() == (yy[0]+yy[1]+yy[2]+yy[3])+(yy[4]+yy[5]+yy[6]+yy[7])
Out[147]: True
```

---

Related NumPy developer discussions:

- [numpy.sum is not stable](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8786)
- [implementation of pairwise summation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/3685)
- [implementing a numerically stable sum](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2448)

`numpy.sum` does not use [Kahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) nor Shewchuk summation (used by `math.fsum`). I believe these algorithms would
produce a stable result under the zero-padding issue that you've raised but I'm not expert enough to say for sure.

Comment: Accepting the answer rather late than never. Rereading it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You might be running into floating-point precision issues at this point.

By default, numpy uses double precision floats for storing the values, with 16 digits of precision. The first result outputs 17 digits.

I suspect that in the former case the fluctuations in values result in the two values being rounded *slightly* differently, with the former being resulting in a rounding to a half (5.5e-16), and the latter exceeding the threshold to be rounded to a full number (6.0e-16).

However, this is just a hypothesis - I don't know for sure how numpy does rounding for the least significant digit.